# global variable does not changed after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using below code

```
var lockonscreens = 1;

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    var noOfSelection = 0; 

        if(lockonscreens == 0){
            // some stuff
        }
        if(lockonscreens == 1){
            // some stuff
        } 

});

function ajaxcall(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:
        type:
        data:
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            lockonscreens = data;
        }
    });
}

jQuery("#").click(function(){
ajaxcall();
});
```

I am using above code to get some data through ajax and set it to variable and depending on that variable a click event code may happen.

But on ajax call the global variable value doesn't get changed.
It remains the same even if the data changes in ajax.

Can anyone let me know what is the issue and how to correct it?

Comment: this variable is used also at the other places than click event.

Comment: where have u called d function ajaxcall() ??

Comment: it is called through click on some link

Comment: Most likly you are running the code using the global variable while the ajax call is running. Make sure the ajax request is completed before running any code using the new global variable value

Comment: are you sure that the second click is happening after the ajax request is completed? and that the ajax request is successfully completed

Comment: yes, ajax requested is successfully completed.

Comment: please provide code where you call the ajax function and where you want to use the global variable. The ajax call can be completed successfully but since javascript is asynchronous the code will continue to run regardless of the ajax call, ergo the global variable is error prone to be used before it is changed.

Comment: I'm taking it you've removed the `url`, `type` and `data` values for the example?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that ajax is **asynchronous**, so if you call `ajaxCall()` and next an other function, ajax start the call to server and the function end.

When the server respond, the code after `success:` is executed.

Make sure you call the function in the `success:` function